# This address should never have been indexed, how can I properly remove it?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, search-engines

I have a couple of subdomains on my website that I use for various purposes and I don't want/need them to be indexed by search engines. From the very beginning, since I created them, I added a `robots.txt` file to disallow search engines from crawling those pages.

Now, I know that this does not enforce anything, it's just a "guideline" for search engines. But in respect to Google, they have lots of help documents suggesting the use of robots.txt, so I believe they respect that file.

Anyway, one of those sub domains is still indexed and I can't understand why. Like I said, this has been created with the disallow rules in robots.txt since the very beginning that sub domain went life and it's been running like this for 2 years or so. Still, I just noticed this:

[image]

**How can I permanently get rid of this indexed result on Google?** For the record, Bing and Yahoo! don't have a result for the same query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google has a removal tool that may work for you, here's an overview page from their sea of help pages:

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=164734

Comment: What really bothers me is that those pages should have never been indexed. Bing and Yahoo don't index the, why does Google? Forcing me to remove them manually...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the site and the index will go away shortly. There is no reliable way to have a site operate but not be indexed.

Comment: I can't remove the site, I need it online...